# VPS and WAMPSERVER

Tags: wamp, hosting, vps

I have a vps server, i installed wamp server on it when i access

```
http://localhost/
```

it looks like this: [See image](http://s29.postimg.org/go2d1dw3b/screenshot_116.png)

when i access the public ip address it looks like this: [See image](http://s29.postimg.org/s1owcl6lz/screenshot_117.png)

when I access the private ip address on the VPS it looks like this: [See image](http://s29.postimg.org/vmkrvtb5j/screenshot_118.png)

And when I access Private ip address on my pc it looks like this: [See image](http://s29.postimg.org/xfnok4wc7/screenshot_119.png)

My question is what I need to make to access wamp from my pc or outer the VPS?

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer is designed to be a developers tool to be used on a developers desktop PC.

For this reason it comes configured in a way that is designed to protect the newbie from themselves and therefore Apache is configured to only accept connections from the PC running Apache, for obvious security reasons.

If you want to allow access from other locations you have to change the Apache configuration.

The quick and simple, and of course **most dangerous** method is to use the `Put Online` menu option on the wampmanager menu.

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

That will change the Apache config ( httpd.conf ) to allow access from any ip adddress in the universe. **That may not be what you really want to do** so alternatively you can manually edit the `httpd.conf` file ( use the wampmanager menus to do this )

```
wampmanager->Apache->httpd.conf
```

Find this section of the file

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

It may look like this is your have done a `Put Online`

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

And change it to allow specific ip address's or address ranges into your system

A specific ip ( your PC lets say ) while you are developing, Add the line

```
Require from 111.222.333.444
```

You and a friend

```
Require from 111.222.333.444 222.333.444.555
```

A whole subnet

```
Require 111.222.333
```

Remember, you will not be adding your internal ip address, 192.168.?.? you will be using your routers WAMP ip.

Basically you should read this part of the Apache manual